# digital alarm clock widget

Tags: customization

I am looking for a digtal alarm clock widget since a long time for my wordpress site. It should be configurable in the GUI as well. Also it should have no flash because the ipad and iphone do not support flash.I couldnt find in the widgets and plugins area so i tried the google gadgets, it was having other issues. Can anyone of you help me in this please.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. It sounds like you're asking us to build this program for you.

Comment: No not really, i just want one close to my specs, if anyone has used it or seen in the plugins or gadgets area

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+clock+script

Comment: This isn't helpful at all, while the question is fairly ambiguous and it possibly easily solved with not too long on Google, posting a Google search link as an answer, with no other explaination is generally just rude.

Comment: Pardon, but I'm not fully understanding why it's rude to highlight a google search on a site advertised as "for WP developers and administrators"... It can't be that hard to take any of the resulting scripts and paste it into a text widget, can it?

Comment: In general, [just posting a Google link is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) on the main Stack Overflow site, or just [plain banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links). As noted in one of the responses, [I sometimes circumvent this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/hosting-wordpress-on-azure/3011#3011) by "wrapping" it in a sentence with a link to the first result. And indeed, we aim for developers, but not every visitor has the same level of experience.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to find a JavaScript-powered alarm clock and paste the code into a standard Text widget.  It wouldn't be configurable in the UI (to my knowledge, there are not any existing WordPress plug-ins that build an alarm clock and expose a UI like this) ... but it shouldn't be too hard to find a configurable JavaScript clock and drop it on a page.

A quick Google search turned up a [Cut & Paste JavaScript Alarm Clock](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/alarm.shtml).  It's an entire form that displays the time, lets you set the time, and lets you set a specific action to fire when the alarm goes off.  It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it should point you in the right direction.