# Hosting WordPress on Azure?

Tags: hosting

Can I host WordPress/WordPress MU installation on Microsoft's Azure cloud platform?

Does anyone have any advice or experience hosting WordPress on Azure?

Comment: Actually, it depends how do you want to host it within Azure?
As for what it is, you could check the Azure MarketPlace and look for WordPress.. many alternatives are available right there (mostly with some 3rd party Azure PaaS providers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress seems to be [one of the poster children of PHP on Azure](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415054145/http://wordpress.visitmix.com/), so you can find [many resources explaining how to install it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimoneil/windows-azure-companion-php-and-wordpress-in-azure).

Comment: The Visitmix update is dead and should be relinked.